# Storing and then Sorting multiple Json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I read this [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects) excellent post on how to sort the objects retrieved from Json. However, I couldn't find a way if I want to access particular element of the array. For example,

if we have this -:

```
var homes = [{
   "h_id": "3",
   "city": "Dallas",
   "state": "TX",
   "zip": "75201",
   "price": "162500"
}, {
   "h_id": "4",
   "city": "Bevery Hills",
   "state": "CA",
   "zip": "90210",
   "price": "319250"
}, {
   "h_id": "5",
   "city": "New York",
   "state": "NY",
   "zip": "00010",
   "price": "962500"
}];
```

In my array I have objects like

```
for (i to n)
var date = -----something----
var message = -----something----
    var homes=[{date,message}]
```

Now after sorting, if I wish to access date and store it somewhere, How will I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you want inject home data into your JSON data array?

Comment: @blueiur I am sorry, I didnt understand what you meant. I want to access "message/date" that is stored in homes.

Comment: please write your json data structure.

Comment: (If this is what you are asking for?)

char * pJson = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (pnb.str().length() + 1));
strcpy(pJson, pnb.str().c_str());
*output = pJson;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your json is array of objects, you can push the object into array using array.push() method like the following :

```
homes.push({date:new Date(), message :"shreedhar"});
```

if you want to push the date and message into each object in your json, you can do so like following :

```
for( var i=0; i<homes.length;i++){
homes[i].message = "some msg";
homes[i].date = "some date";
}
console.log(homes);
```

now if you want to access the anything inside the json

```
homes[0].message; // gives you "some msg"
homes[0].date; // gives you "some date"
```

Comment: Actually I have already done that. To store them in an array I have done the same as you mentioned, now if I want to access message shreedhar above, how will I do that?

and the second part "for loop" that you mentioned. I dont want to do that, as I am implementing the sorting algorithm I mentioned in the links in my question

Comment: @UnderDog i have edited my answer please have a look at it :)

Comment: so you mean, if I use 
var homes=[{date,message}]
and I can access them using homes[0].messsage

Comment: yes var homes=[{date:"date",message:"msg"}], can be accessible lik homes[0].message //it will gives you msg.

Comment: That will be awesome if it really works that way. Lemme try and get back to you. Is it possible to contact you (regarding the same) on the gmail_id you have mentioned on your profile link?